# "Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string" when running xampp installer file

Tags: software-installation, xampp

I want to install XAMPP on my machine. I downloaded the install file from [this website](https://www.apachefriends.org/fr/index.html) and stored it in my default Downloads directory. The site gives instructions on how to install it, then.

I followed these instructions as below:

```
chmod 755 xampp-linux-x64-5.6.12-0-installer.run
```

Then:

```
sudo ./xampp-linux-x64-5.6.12-0-installer.run
```

I get the following message:

```
./xampp-linux-x64-5.6.12-0-installer.run: 
1: ./xampp-linux-x64-5.6.12-0-installer.run: 
Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

The `file` command returns:

> xampp-linux-x64-5.6.12-0-installer.run: ELF 64-bit LSB  executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked, stripped

I can't find what the problem is... This is quite a basic command, isn't it?

Thanks for help!

Comment: That makes no sense. What you describe should have worked. What's the output of `file xampp-linux-x64-5.6.12-0-installer.run`? Are you sure you are running the right file?

Comment: Were you copy-pasting those commands somewhere from a tutorial ?

Comment: What do you call 'the output of the file'? I did not copy-paste commands.

Comment: @wiltomap `file` is a command that gives information on the file you run it on. So, `file xampp-linux-x64-5.6.12-0-installer.run` will tell us what you downloaded. Just open a terminal and run it. Also, we're discussing this question in the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room), you might want to drop by.

Comment: @wiltomap there is a terminal command called `file`. Just type in terminal `file xampp-linux-x64-5.6.12-0-installer.run` Make sure you're in the same directory as the file

Comment: Just edited my post including file command result.

Comment: Are you running a 32bit system?

Comment: uname -a command returns: Linux thomas-MS-7918 3.16.0-38-generic #52~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 8 09:44:48 UTC 2015 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

Comment: indeed, 32-bit. i686 isn't 64-bit =)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Judging by the error you are getting, and found on this site [here](https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?p=244870&sid=149d2efb396bdfee33a29bd2df9e7954), the error can occur when you are installing a `64bit` version of the program on a `32bit` system.

What does the command `uname -a` return on your system?  If you see anything other than `x86_64` in that line, then download the `32bit` version of the application.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Bingo, OP's system says i686

Comment: OK thanks a lot! I'll try the 32-bit version.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following steps because your system is configured with 32 bit:-

```
sudo chmod 755 xampp-linux-x64-5.6.12-0-installer.run
sudo ./xampp-linux-5.6.12-0-installer.run
```